# Nested for loop to print a set of values from array list

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

I am creating a program to display an array list of poker decks. So far, i have two enum sets that are the suits and ranks. I am able to display them as such

`S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 SJ SQ SK SA H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 HJ HQ HK HA D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 DJ DQ DK DA C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 CJ CQ CK CA`

However, is there a way that i can use nested for loops to split the suits and display them separately as shown below?

`S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8 S9 S10 SJ SQ SK SA
 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7 H8 H9 H10 HJ HQ HK HA
 D2 D3 D4 D5 D6 D7 D8 D9 D10 DJ DQ DK DA
 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 CJ CQ CK CA`

This is what i have tried so far:

**Display Deck method**

```
private static final int MAXC = 13;
private static final int MAXD = 52;

private static void displayDeck(ArrayList<Decks> values)


{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXD; i++)
    {
    // this prints the entire deck out  
    System.out.printf ("%s", values.get(i));

    }
}
```

I tried this nested for loop but to no avail

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXD; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < MAXC; j++)
        {
    System.out.printf ("%s", values.get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

**Add deck method**

```
    // enhanced for loop to add every single card into the arrayList
private void addDeck(ArrayList<Decks> values)
{
    for(SuitEnum s : SuitEnum.values ())
    {
        for(RankEnum r : RankEnum.values ())
        {
            values.add(new PlayingCard(s,r));
        }
    }

}
```

**Main method**

```
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
      ArrayList<Decks> list = new ArrayList<Decks>();  

      decks test = new decks ();
      test.addDeck(list);
      printDeck(list);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXD; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < MAXC; j++)
        {
           System.out.printf ("%s", values.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXD; i++)
    {
        for(int j =0; j < MAXC; j++)
        {
            int index = i + j * MAXD;
            System.out.printf ("%s", values.get(index));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private void addDeck(ArrayList<Decks> values)
{
    int suiteLength = SuitEnum.values().length;
    int rankLength = RankEnum.values().length;
    for(int i=0; i<suiteLength; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<rankLength; j++)
        {
             int index = rankLength * i + j;
             System.out.printf ("%s", values.get(index));
        }
    }
}
```